# Determine actual number of columns of css dynamic grid

Tags: javascript, css-grid

I'm using a dynamic number of columns in a css grid like this: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(230px, 100%), 1fr));`.

This works great. However, I would like be able to know in my JavaScript the actual row number. Can I do that without having to recalculate it?

Comment: I think you need to recalculate using according to min max value of the columns and on screen readjustment. There no way to get the number out of css

Comment: There's a proposed column combinator [`F || E`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-column-combinator) in the CSS Selectors Level 4 specs, this may imply an eventual ability to do this more easily (if the browser engine has to calculate the columns anyway), but currently I don't believe it's possible (unfortunately). If you want help with that (if recalculating is acceptable), then you'll need to post some representative content, if you know how to do it already then you may want to close/delete the question itself.

Comment: Thanks, will do (calculating it should not be a problem)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's currently not possible